# select sum of max in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Based off the following table schema, I want to be able to select the sum of the maximum of each submission. A student can have multiple submissions for a contest, so their total score is the sum of the maximum score of each contest. Right now my query selects student_id, name, and maximum score of all their contests, how can I get the sum of the max of all their contest? The expected output based on the input should be:

```
select student_id, name, max(score) as TotalScore
from students2 as st
join submissions as s
where st.student_id = s.student_id
group by st.student_id, name
having count(*) > 1
order by TotalScore desc;
```

Comment: update your question  add  a proper data sample and the expected  result ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select student_id, name, sum(TotalScore) total_sum
from (select st.student_id student_id
             , name 
             , max(score) as TotalScore
from students as st
join submissions as s
on st.student_id = s.student_id
group by s.contest_id, s.student_id)
group by student_id;
```

[Here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e2a77/9)

I have started to create a demo before your sample data...

From your text in your question I did not understood what do you need `having count(*) > 1` for so I did not used it.

**Please note**: I have used `students` as the name of the table and not `students2`.

Comment: Very elite answer

Comment: @forpas what does that mean? this was answered at the same time. Your code is nto as mine and I have mine fiddle ???

Comment: @forpas answers are not the same. You did not posted earlier. Both 9 mins ago.

Comment: you both did great

Answer (score 0):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
select student_id, name, sum(max_score) as TotalScore
from students2 st join
     (select s.student_id, max(score) as max_score
      from submissions s
      group by s.student_id
     ) s
     on st.student_id = s.student_id
group by st.student_id, name
having count(*) > 1;
order by TotalScore desc;
```

I notice that your `FROM` clause is using `JOIN` but missing the `ON` clause.  You should get used to always including that.

Comment: This doesn't return the desired output - if you see the updated post I included the inputed data and what should be outputted

Comment: to be more specific, this outputs ```3 Jim 245```